# How do you configure the FROM field in a jetty email configuration?

Tags: email, jetty, jakarta-mail, archiva

I'm configuring version 1.4-M3 of Archiva running standalone with Jetty.
The configuration works (I get the emails). However, they're being reported from "root@localhost". As you can see in the configuration below I have mail.from defined, but somehow it is not being picked up. No mail header contains the address archiva@mymailserver.com.

**What is the correct configuration so emails are shown as being sent from archiva@mymailserver.com?**

```
  <New id="validation_mail" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
<Arg>mail/Session</Arg>
<Arg>
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jndi.factories.MailSessionReference">
    <Set name="user">myuser</Set>
    <Set name="password">OBF:1yxf1vnw1v1p1vu51vv51v2p1vn61ym5</Set>
    <Set name="properties">
      <New class="java.util.Properties">
        <Put name="mail.smtp.host">mail.server</Put>
        <Put name="mail.smtp.auth">true</Put>
        <Put name="mail.port">25</Put>
        <Put name="mail.from">archiva@mymailserver.com</Put>
        <Put name="mail.mime.address.strict">false</Put>
        <Put name="mail.debug">false</Put>
        <Put name="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</Put>
      </New>
    </Set>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

Comment: flip mail.debug to true and see what the logs say, that might provide some insight

Answer (score 0):

According to Archiva's documentation, the email address is configured using the following property:

> - email.from.address=$user.name@localhost
>     Blockquote
>
>   - All emails sent by the system will be from the following address

As of Archiva 2.1.x and 2.2.x, I don't see that property listed within the Properties tab of the Users Runtime Configuration section.  That means that you'll need to manually set this property in archiva.xml.  In case you're using a servlet container, such as Tomcat, I don't mean the archiva.xml that's located within conf/Catalina/localhost.  I'm referring to the archiva.xml that's located immediately within the conf directory.

[Source - Archiva's Email Configuration page](https://archiva.apache.org/redback/configuration.html#Email_Settings)